# Text data massaging to conduct distance calculations in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to get text data from dataframe "A" to be convereted to columns while text data from dataframe "B" to be in rows in a new dataframe "C" in order to calculate distance calculations.

```
Data in dataframe "A" looks like this

Unique -> header

'Amy'
'little'
'sheep'
'dead'

Data in dataframe "B" looks like this

common_words -> header

'Amy'
'George'
'Barbara'
```

i want the output in dataframe C as

```
     Amy  George   Barbara
Amy
little
sheep
dead
```

Can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What should be the actual content of data frame `C`? Do you only want to initialise it to some value (i.e. `0`) in the first step and then fill it with the distance calculations?

You could initialise `C` in the following way:

```
import pandas as pd

A = pd.DataFrame(['Amy', 'little', 'sheep', 'dead'])
B = pd.DataFrame(['Amy', 'George', 'Barbara'])

C = pd.DataFrame([[0] * len(B)] * len(A), index=A[0], columns=B[0])
```

`C` will then look like:

```
        Amy George  Barbara
0           
Amy     0   0   0
little  0   0   0
sheep   0   0   0
dead    0   0   0
```

Comment: Is it possible to add in Euclidean distance in here instead of zero's? Also I am getting a key error 0

Comment: How would you define Euclidean distance on strings? For string distance calculation you could use [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

Please `pd.DataFrame(index =[list],columns =[list])`

Extract the relevant lists using `list(df.columnname.values)`

Dummy data

```
print(dfA)

    Header
0     Amy
1  little
2   sheep
3    dead

print(dfB)
   Header
0      Amy
1   George
2  Barbara

dfC=pd.DataFrame(index=list(dfA.Header.values), columns=list(dfB.Header.values))

       Amy George Barbara
Amy     NaN    NaN     NaN
little  NaN    NaN     NaN
sheep   NaN    NaN     NaN
dead    NaN    NaN     NaN
```

If interested in `dfC` without `NaNS`. Please

```
dfC=pd.DataFrame(index=list(dfA.Header.values), columns=list(dfB.Header.values)).fillna(' ')

     Amy George Barbara
Amy                      
little                   
sheep                    
dead
```

Comment: Is it possible to put in eucledan distance in this?

Comment: How do you want the distances put?

Comment: am posting a seperate question on that thanks for the help